# Changing views keeps giving me attempt to present vc1 on vc whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I've created a test application to understand how views/viewcontrollers work and how to navigate between them programmatically without a storyboard or a nib.

I've basically set up a `rootViewController` called Viewcontroller which is set in the `AppDelegate`.

This view presents view1 on startup which contains a uibutton which calls the notification in the `rootViewController` to present view2. However when I do this I keep getting the warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <View1: 0x7be66c80> on <ViewController: 0x7be62980> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

My code for the controlling viewcontroller is as follows:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "View1.h"
    #import "View2.h"
    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    -(void) loadView{
        [super loadView];
    }
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        NSLog(@"View appeared");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"view1" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(view1:) name:@"view1" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"view2" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(view2:) name:@"view2" object:nil];
        [self showView1];
    }
    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    -(void)view1:(NSNotification*) notification{
        NSLog(@"Showing view1");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [self showView1];
    }
    -(void)showView1{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:[[View1 alloc]init] animated:YES completion:nil];
        });
    }
    -(void)view2:(NSNotification*) notification{
        NSLog(@"Showing view2");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [self showView2];
    }
    -(void)showView2{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self presentViewController:[[View1 alloc]init] animated:YES completion:nil];
        });
    }

@end
```

Edit:I forgot to mention that view1 displays initially without any errors or problems.

Edit: the code for view1 and view2 are exactly identical except that they send different notifications:

```
    #import "View1.h"

    @interface View1 ()

    @end

    @implementation View1

    - (void)loadView {
        [super loadView];
        self.view.frame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bounds];
        // Do view setup here.
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(touchedLogin:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        button.layer.cornerRadius=1;
        button.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2-100, self.view.bounds.size.height-200, 200, 60.0);
        [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];

        //[_window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:button];
    }
    -(void)touchedLogin:(id*)sender{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"view2" object:nil];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: If you get the error when you press the button in View1, then you need to show the code you have in that button's action method.

Comment: I've added the code. Both views are the same except the other one sends the notification to show the other view

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you're dismissing View1 with `animation`, then immediately calling showView2 (which actually shows View1, since you have `[View1 alloc]init]` in that method). Because the animation takes some amount of time, you're trying to present View1 while View1 is still on screen, not `ViewController`. In general, it's not a good idea to do dismissals and presentations, one right after the other like that. I think it might work (though I never do this) if you do the dismissal without animation.

Comment: I've tried removing all animations and the error still comes up. I've also tried using dispatch async on the dismissal and presentation with no success

Comment: @thegalah, yeah, I wasn't sure that would work. Using dispatch_async is unnecessary in your code since everything is on the main thread. Your whole approach is not good. Don't do a presentation right after a dismissal. If you want to go from View1 to View2, have View1 present View2. Also, using notifications like you are isn't the best way to go either. They're best used when you have multiple controllers that need to be notified of some action, not just one like you have here.

Comment: How would I navigate between the views as I wish to. I'm new to ios haha

Comment: @thegalah, that's too broad a question for me to answer. There are many ways to do it, and many structures that your app could take. Often the root view controller would be one of the container controllers like a navigation controller, tab bar controller, or split view controller. I suggest you  read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS", and also the "View Controller Catalog for iOS" to get a good overview of the possibilities.

Comment: I think I've found the proper way to change views. It's not really changing views but it works. Basically I add the initialized viewcontroller as a childviewcontroller and add the viewcontrollers view as a subview using the following:
`UIViewController * vc=[[View2 alloc]init];
        [self addChildViewController:vc];
        [self.view addSubview:vc.view];`